# How to specify ansible pretasks for a role?

Tags: dependencies, ansible, role

How should one go about defining a pretask for role dependencies.
I currently have an `apache` role that has a user variable so in my own role in `<role>/meta/main.yml` I do something like:

```
---
dependencies:
  - { role: apache, user: proxy }
```

The problem at this point is that I still don't have the user I specify and when the role tries to start `apache` server under a non existent user, I get an error.

I tried creating a task in `<role>/tasks/main.yml` like:

```
---
- user: name=proxy
```

But the user gets created only after running the `apache` task in dependencies (which is to be expected). So, is there a way to create a task that would create a user before running roles in dependencies?

Comment: Can you post full playbook as well as your custom role?

Comment: Also did you put `- user: name=proxy` as a `pre_tasks:` or a `tasks` in `<role>/tasks/main.yml` ?

Comment: Actually, except for the `---` part a line above the `- user: name=proxy` that's the whole file I have. I've edited the content to make it more clear how exactly my files look but that's about all I have now except for the apache role

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of Ansible 2.2, you can use `include_role`.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_role_module.html

```
- user: name=proxy

- include_role:
    name: apache
  vars:
    user: proxy
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this can go in `tasks/main.yml` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: As of Ansible 2.4 there's also import_role now https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_role_module.html

Answer (score 68):

I use the **pre_tasks** to do some tasks before roles, thanks for [Kashyap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29264713/686105).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook

---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  pre_tasks:
    - name: start tasks and sent notifiaction to HipChat
      hipchat:
        color: purple
        token: "{{ hipchat_token }}"
        room: "{{ hipchat_room }}"
        msg: "[Start] Run 'foo/setup.yml' playbook on {{ ansible_nodename }}."

  roles:
    - chusiang.vim-and-vi-mode

  vars:
    ...

  tasks:
    - name: include main task
      include: tasks/main.yml

  post_tasks:
    - name: finish tasks and sent notifiaction to HipChat
      hipchat:
        color: green
        token: "{{ hipchat_token }}"
        room: "{{ hipchat_room }}"
        msg: "[Finish] Run 'foo/setup.yml' playbook on {{ ansible_nodename }}."

# vim:ft=ansible :
```

Comment: Right now, I like use the `pre_tasks` and `post_tasks` to do something.

Answer (score 12):

You could simply solve this with another dependency either in your unnamed `<role>` or in the `apache` role.

Whole content of a new proxy-user role:

```
---
- user: name=proxy
...
```

Then in `roles/apache/meta/main.yml` add a dependency to it.

```
---
dependencies:
  - proxy-user
...
```

Or set it in `roles/<role>/meta/main.yml`:

```
---
dependencies:
  - proxy-user
  - { role: apache, user: proxy }
...
```

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: I don't think the language allows specifying `pre_tasks` for roles.

You could cheat/work-around by moving creation of user to a separate playbook and `include`ing the playbook instead of `role`. Something like this:

my_fake_role_playbooks/user_and_apache.yml:

```
- hosts: "{{p_hosts}}"
  pre_tasks:
    user: name=proxy
  roles: [ apache ]
```

actual_playbook.yml:

```
- include: my_fake_role_playbooks/user_and_apache.yml p_hosts=[host1, host2]
```

* code is untested.

HTH

Comment: Are `pre_tasks` and `post_task` only allowed in playbooks and not in roles?

Comment: There are now `include_vars`, `include_tasks`, and `include_roles` modules.  These are modules, so they run as tasks, pre_tasks, or post_tasks, in roles or tasks, possibly even handlers.

Yes, `pre_tasks`, and `post_tasks`, are used in playbooks, not roles.  To be strict, the `tasks` section is only used in playbooks as well, since role tasks are in a separate file.

Answer (score 8):

Just had to deal with the problem, the real issue is that the pre-task is very likely somewhat more specific than the role.  Doing a post-task is easy, because you would simply make a new role dependant, this is known as a 
"wrapper role"... or at least that's what they call the idea in chef, for when your trying to extend something.

For a pre-task, you have to modify the hierarchy a bit, using a "wrapper role" and what I call a "sibling role".  So the dependency logic would appear as,

- wrapper role

  - sibling role
  - original role

The wrapper has two dependencies, but make sure to add the "sibling role" first in the dependency list.  Since Ansible will go from top to bottom.

Finally, you should place your vars in the wrapper role, so that you could overwrite them from the playbook. You want the variables to follow the hierarchy, as much as possible, and not jump across the siblings.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar need, and I solved it by defining the variable in the role vars. That is, creating a `<role>/vars/main.yml` with

```
---
user: proxy
```

that should override the `user` variable defined at apache module, while writing it in your module `defaults` directory doesn't.

I'm using ansible 1.9, not sure how long this behaviour has been present.